# Installing zerofree on Centos 7 bare

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I am trying to reclaim free disk space from a VirtualBox VM with Centos 7 as the guest OS.

All of the resources I found online recommend using `zerofree` to zero out the free disk space before compacting the image. They all install `zerofree` using yum, however, I'm not able to find `zerofree` in the main Centos repo nor the EPEL repo. Is this tool not available/recommended on Centos 7? How can I install it or is there a substitute for Centos 7?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the epel-release repositories.

- `sudo yum install epel-release`
- `sudo yum install zerofree`